# Java Cassandra connectivity

Tags: java, cassandra, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError which is caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. I have added cassandra-driver-core-2.1.7.jar in build path. No compile time error but during runtime I'm getting above exception.

```
public class SimpleClient {
       private Cluster cluster;    
       public void connect(String node) {
           System.getProperties();
           try{
              cluster = Cluster.builder() ---> Here I'm getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
                    .addContactPoint(node).build();
              Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
              System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n", 
                    metadata.getClusterName());
              for ( Host host : metadata.getAllHosts() ) {
                 System.out.printf("Datatacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s\n",
                       host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack());
              }
           }catch(Exception e){
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
       }

       public void close() {
          cluster.close();
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          SimpleClient client = new SimpleClient();
          System.getProperties();
          client.connect("127.0.0.1");
          client.close();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the exception?  It would be useful to know what is missing.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:64)
 at SimpleClient.connect(SimpleClient.java:11)
 at SimpleClient.main(SimpleClient.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass

Comment: I see, I think you need to add the slf4j-api.jar file to your classpath.

Comment: Yeah, this really isn't a duplicate...and the linked question doesn't have anything to do with Cassandra.  This problem is actually semi-common to see while getting started on a new Cassandra project.